# PHP authenticating registered users

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

When you authenticate registered users you make request e.g. one examples i found:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pw = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT user,password FROM users 
    WHERE user='$user' 
    AND password='$pw' 
    LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($result)){
    //we have a match!
}else{
    //no match
}
```

Now what would be the benefit or any point of having `LIMIT 1` at the end?
And why you need to select user and password when you can just select user_id?

Would not the

```
SELECT user_id FROM users
WHERE user = '{$user}'
AND password = '{$pw}'
```

be same exact logistics but shorter code?

EDIT: thinking about this little detail made me find one more check to prevent hackers.
There should not be more than one user with same email and password so if they somehow supply instead of password `123` e.g. string `' OR password = '*'` (or similar logics) this will compromise my query, having no limit would help because next step i can count

```
if (count($result) > 1) {
   echo "we got hacked";
else 
   <proceed...>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you will have a unique `user` column, so `LIMIT 1` is not necessary - you won't have more than 1 row anyway.

In this case, it might be a decorative element - self explaining syntax to tell a programmer that reads a code, that query is expected to return no more than one row.

Aside from your question, I would strongly recommend to use some password encryption, for example `MD5()`. A tutorial that teaches you to store a plain passwords is not the best one...

Comment: Yep i did that but md5 is not safe by itself because of many websites with databases that save hash and original string i think something like crc32(md5(hash("sha256",$_POST['password']))) would be much better

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have only a single row in the database for each username/password pair, the LIMIT clause improves performance by discontinuing the search after the first match is found, primarily when used in conjunction with an ORDER BY clause.

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html):

> If you use LIMIT row_count with ORDER BY, MySQL ends the sorting as soon as it has found the first row_count rows of the sorted result, rather than sorting the entire result. If ordering is done by using an index, this is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can read "[SQL Injection: How To Prevent Security Flaws In PHP / MySQL](http://www.learnphponline.com/security/sql-injection-prevention-mysql-php)" and see how your login might be useless without proper measures.

Everything else was answered by far wiser posters above.

Comment: Ok thanks, but i am not asking about thins at moment it was just sample query the question was about last line of it not about security in general. so far i use mysql_real_escape_string() to process input data.

Comment: Then, if you just want the auth part, go ahead and shorten it as you see fit. The LIMIT 1 at the end is a valid optimisation, though.
SQL "don't know" that is a login function, nor does it know there is exacatly 1 record (or none) to be found and WILL search for matches throughout the table.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases your table will hold unique usernames so you will always get back 1 or 0 rows. And as such as far as your code is concerned it doesn't make a difference. Even if you had multiple rows returned your code would still work, as you are only checking for existence of rows and not how many of them have been returned (but it would be wrong, as you wouldn't know which user actually logged in).

Basically it just tells MySQL to stop searching the table after the first row that meets the conditions in WHERE is found. In some cases even this could be redundant (if you had a UNIQUE index on the "user" field for instance).

One more thing not related to your question: please do not use this code for anything but learning. It's full of security holes. Google for "SQL injection" and "storing password securely" before you put this code into production.

Answer (score -1):

Firs you need to sanitize strings from injection:

```
class main{
public function sanitize($str,$remove_nl=true)
        {
            stripslashes($str);

            if($remove_nl)
            {
                $injections = array('/(\n+)/i',
                    '/(\r+)/i',
                    '/(\t+)/i',
                    '/(%0A+)/i',
                    '/(%0D+)/i',
                    '/(%08+)/i',
                    '/(%09+)/i'
                    );
                $str = preg_replace($injections,'',$str);
            }

            return $str;
        }
}
```

Next yours code:

```
$main_class = new main();

$user = $main_class->sanitize(trim($_POST['user']));
$pw = $main_class->sanitize(trim($_POST['password']));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user`='".$user."' AND `password`='".$pw."' LIMIT 0,1";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count > 0){
    //we have a match!
}else{
    //no match
}
```

Comment: Can i just use mysql_real_escape_string()? and why it has to be class and object, not just function?

Comment: Yes, but this real_escape_string not delete special symbols as in `$injections` array in my example.

Actually I highly recommend to use `mysqli` to prevent all injections by default expressions, and with `mysqli` you do not need to escape strings from special symbols at all